# Unable to start solr node with sysprop to form a nodeset

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am trying to apply some cluster level autoscaling policies and for that I am trying to create a nodeset.
There are some of the ways to create a nodeset(selecting a set of nodes on basis of some rules) as per docs : https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_3/solrcloud-autoscaling-policy-preferences.html#node-selection-attributes

The docs state that we can use sysprop.{PROPERTY_NAME}: to specify a set of nodes.and  sysprop.key means a value that is passed to the node as -Dkey=keyValue during the node startup.

So this is the command I am using to start a node

```
bin/solr start -cloud -s example/cloud/node/solr -p 8987 -Dkey=noderef -z localhost:9983
```

However I get the following error after the above command

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down.
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:370)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1711)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1678)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Can anyone point out what I am doing here. basically I want to label a set of nodes as "pullnodes" and other set as "tlognodes" so that I can apply different alutoscaling cluster policies to the same**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a syntax issue, need to pass the key-value in quotes like this

```
bin/solr start -cloud -s example/cloud/node/solr -p 8987 "-Dkey=noderef" -z localhost:9983
```

Also it doesn't seem to work in local cloud mode, tried the above command with nodes on seperate machine and it worked